# Show $\cos\frac\gamma2=\sqrt{\frac{p(p-c)}{ab}}$

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, solution-verification, euclidean-geometry, triangles

> Show that the equality $$\cos\dfrac{\gamma}{2}=\sqrt{\dfrac{p(p-c)}{ab}}$$ holds for a $\triangle ABC$ with sides $AB=c,BC=a, AC=b$, semi-perimeter $p$ and $\measuredangle ACB=\gamma$.

[image]

I have just proved that $$l_c=\dfrac{2ab\cos\dfrac{\gamma}{2}}{a+b}$$

Is this a well known formula for angle bisectors?

Can we use it somehow?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Yes, it is a known formula ; see for example slide 4 [here](https://www.slideshare.net/indupsthakur/solution-of-triangles).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Form half-angle trig-identity

$$\cos\gamma=2\cos^2\frac{\gamma}{2}-1\iff \cos \frac{\gamma}{2}=\sqrt{\frac{1+\cos\gamma}{2}}$$

Substituting the value from cosine formula: $\cos \gamma=\frac{a^2+b^2-c^2}{2ab}$
$$\cos \frac{\gamma}{2}=\sqrt{\frac{1+\frac{a^2+b^2-c^2}{2ab}}{2}}$$
$$=\sqrt{\frac{(a+b)^2-c^2}{4ab}}$$

$$=\sqrt{\frac{(a+b+c)(a+b-c)}{4ab}}$$
$$=\sqrt{\frac{\left(\frac{a+b+c}{2}\right)\left(\frac{a+b+c}{2}-c\right)}{ab}}$$
$$=\sqrt{\frac{p(p-c)}{ab}}$$

Comment: Thank you for the response! I haven't actually studied this identity (half-angle trig-identity). How can I derive it?

Comment: Also can I ask you how did you simplify $\dfrac{(a+b+c)(a+b-c)}{4ab}$ to $\dfrac{\left(\dfrac{a+b+c}{2}\right)\left(\dfrac{a+b+c}{2}-c\right)}{ab}$?

Comment: Well, you can proceed as follows $$=\frac{(a+b+c)(a+b-c)}{4ab}$$
$$=\frac{\left(\frac{a+b+c}{2}\right)\left(\frac{a+b-c}{2}\right)}{ab}$$ $$=\frac{\left(\frac{a+b+c}{2}\right)\left(\frac{a+b+c-2c}{2}\right)}{ab}$$ $$=\frac{\left(\frac{a+b+c}{2}\right)\left(\frac{a+b+c}{2}-c\right)}{ab}$$

Comment: I don't get the first part (how do we go from the first to the second line?). Where does the 4 from the denominator go?

Comment: First 2 came from half angle trig-identity and another 2 came from cosine formula i.e. $\cos \gamma$ resulting 4 in denominator. Look carefully from very first line to the  last in my answer

Comment: Sorry, I didn't make myself clear. I mean what does happen with this $4$? Where does it go, because we don't have it on the second line?

Comment: Well, it is distributed in denominators i.e. one 2 goes to $\frac{a+b+c}{2}$ & another 2 goes to $\frac{a+b-c}{2}=\left(\frac{a+b+c}{2}-c\right)$

Comment: Thank you! I got it now.

Comment: Very very nice answer.

Answer (score 4):

We have standard formula for $R = {abc\over 4S}$ and $S = rp$, where $S$ is area and $p$ perimeter of triangle.

[image]

- $\cot {\gamma \over 2} = {p-c\over r}$
- $\sin \gamma  = {c\over 2R}$ (the law of sine)

If we multiply these two we get $$\cos ^2 {\gamma\over 2} = {S(p-c)\over rab} = {p(p-c)\over ab}$$
(Remember that $\sin \gamma = 2\sin{\gamma\over 2}\cos {\gamma \over 2}$)

Comment: Thank you for the response! Can you clarify how by multiplying $\cot\dfrac{\gamma}{2}=\dfrac{p-c}{r}$ by $\sin\gamma=\dfrac{c}{2R}$ we get $cos^2\dfrac{\gamma}{2}=\dfrac{S(p-c)}{rab}=...$?

Comment: @Aqua $p-c$ ....

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate it. +1

Answer (score 3):

Your formula for length of angle bisectors is correct. To derive for sine/cosine of half-angles, a straightforward way is using the formulas : $$1+\cos 2\theta = 2\cos^2 \theta \, , \quad 1-\cos 2\theta = 2\sin^2 \theta$$

By cosine-rule in $\triangle ABC$,
$$\cos \gamma = \frac{a^2+b^2-c^2}{2ab}$$

$$\Rightarrow \cos \frac{\gamma}{2}=\sqrt{\frac{1+\cos \gamma}{2}}$$
which simplifies to

$$ \cos \frac{\gamma}{2}=\sqrt{\frac{p(p-c)}{ab}}$$

Similarly you can also find $\sin (\gamma/2)$, $\tan (\gamma/2)$ etc.

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate it. +1

Answer (score 0):

As for the last part (how we can use the bisector).. The property that the ratio of sides is the ratio in which opposite side $c$ is intersected

$$ e=\dfrac{AC}{ CB}=\dfrac{  AL}{  LB},$$

a constant that defines the Apollonius circle of constant $e$. Bisection can be done either for the internal or for external angle.